# Remove extra space at the end of string using preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

I want to replace the extra space at the end of the string with nothing using `preg_replace` in PHP. I was creating a big database of words and somehow a few words got extra white space at the end.

Answer (score 11):

You should use [`rtrim`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) instead. It will remove extra white space at the end of a string and is faster than using `preg_replace`.

```
$str = "This is a string.    ";
echo rtrim($str);
```

---

**Speed Comparison - `preg_replace` v. `trim`**

```
// Our string
$test = 'TestString    ';

// Test preg_replace
$startpreg = microtime(true);
$preg = preg_replace("/^\s+|\s+$/", "", $test);
$endpreg = microtime(true);

// Test trim
$starttrim = microtime(true);
$trim = rtrim($test);
$endtrim = microtime(true);

// Calculate times
$pregtime = $endpreg - $startpreg;
$trimtime = $endtrim - $starttrim;

// Display results
printf("preg_replace: %f<br/>", $pregtime);
printf("rtrim: %f<br/>", $trimtime);
```

**Results**

> preg_replace: 0.000036
> rtrim: 0.000004

As you can see, `rtrim` is actually [*nine times*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gg07ddQ6T1w) faster.

Answer (score 3):

why not just use trim() http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Comment: why didnt i think about that. Thank you both

Comment: @Matthew Actually, that's incorrect. `trim` tends to be faster than `preg_replace`. As a general rule of thumb, you should use the built-in PHP functions before turning to RegEx.

Comment: @MichaelIrigoyen yes sorry my bad I got them the wrong way round for some reason! http://maettig.com/code/php/php-performance-benchmarks.php

Answer (score 0):

with preg_replace as you wanted :

```
$s = ' okoki efef ef ef   
';

print('-'.$s.'-<br/>');

$s = preg_replace('/\s+$/m', '', $s);

print('-'.$s.'-');
```