# Remove spaces from the beginning and end of a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, whitespace

I am pretty new to regular expressions.
I need to clean up a search string from spaces at the beginning and the end.
Example: " search string "
Result: "search string"

I have a pattern that works as a javascript solution but I cant get it to work on PHP using preg_replace:

Javascript patern that works:

```
/^[\s]*(.*?)[\s]*$/ig
```

My example:

```
$string = preg_replace( '/^[\s]*(.*?)[\s]*$/si', '', " search string " );
print $string; //returns nothing
```

On parse it tells me that g is not recognized so I had to remove it and change the ig to si.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove extra space at the end of string using preg\_replace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787219/remove-extra-space-at-the-end-of-string-using-preg-replace)

Comment: This is a slightly different question than http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787219/remove-extra-space-at-the-end-of-string-using-preg-replace which asks how to remove only the space at end of string where my question is for both start and end. The solution for this is different than the question raised by @daron

Answer (score 74, accepted):

If it's only white-space, why not just use [`trim()`](http://php.net/trim)?

Answer (score 6):

Yep, you should use trim() I guess.. But if you really want that regex, here it is:

```
((?=^)(\s*))|((\s*)(?>$))
```

Comment: thanks this solution works as well: preg_replace( '/^((?=^)(\s*))|((\s*)(?>$))/si', '', " asd asd " );