# Remove all spaces, line breaks, and html breaks from a string generated by ckeditor

Tags: php, regex, ckeditor

I have a bunch of textareas that I am currently using ckeditor on, and storing the values in a database. When I get these values back, I want to be able to tell if nothing was entered into a particular textarea. The problem however is that ckeditor likes to put its own markup and other things into the string even if that textarea was not touched.

So, I need to be able to remove all spaces, line breaks, and html breaks from the beginning and end of a string (since we do not want to erase the good data). Here are the strings I am currently trying to trim (var_dumped from an array),

```
array(3) {
  ["remediation"]=>
  string(26) "


    But not the third
"
  ["effective"]=>
  string(28) "


    Second one is blank
"
  ["celebrate"]=>
  string(6) "
"
}
```

I have already tried the following: trim, [this preg replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022759/remove-spaces-from-the-beginning-and-end-of-a-string), and a number of variations of that preg_replace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `trim` , `strip_tags` with `array_map`

```
$array = array("remediation" => "


    <p> But not the third </p>
","effective" => "


    Second one is blank
","celebrate" => "
");

$array = array_map("strip_tags", $array);
$array = array_map("trim", $array);
var_dump($array);
```

Output

```
array
  'remediation' => string 'But not the third' (length=17)
  'effective' => string 'Second one is blank' (length=19)
  'celebrate' => string '' (length=0)
```

Comment: This is not changing anything, which I am assuming is because of the html in the strings. The first and second element have p tags around them which is fine, but the last has a <br /> in it which needs to go away also.

Comment: Yeah im an idiot, I JUST thought about doing that 5 minutes ago. Not sure why the option did not come to mind in the last 2 hours. I think I have been staring at my screen to long today lol. Thanks for your help man.

Comment: In my case I am actually going to use a temp variable, strip the tags and check the length individually instead of doing it on the whole array, but its the same type of thing. I dont actually want to REMOVE the markup. Just check against it.