# Why does trim function not working correctly for Japanese input?

Tags: php, trim, cjk

I want to [trim](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_trim.asp) full byte spaces from before and after strings. It can contain both Japanese and/or English letters. However, it is not working perfectly for strings starting with hiragana and katakana.

```
//test1
$text = "　　romaji　　";
var_dump(trim($text,"　")); // returns "romaji"

//test2 
$text = "　　ひらがな　　";
var_dump(trim($text,"　")); // returns "��らがな"

//test3
$text = "　　カタカナ　　";
var_dump(trim($text,"　")); // returns "��タカナ"

//test4 
$text = "　　漢字　　";
var_dump(trim($text,"　")); // returns "漢字"
```

Why is the code not working for test 2 and 3? How can we solve it?

Comment: Maybe this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/10067670/4734154 ist helpful. Php trim and UTF-8 may be tricky.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multibyte trim in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10066647/multibyte-trim-in-php) ... solution is there. Non-UTF-8 aware PHP functions are known to potentially mangle multibyte characters. For the record, the "spaces" in your tests are `U+3000 : IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is hard to troubleshoot, more detailed described here

1. [PHP output showing little black diamonds with a question mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275411/php-output-showing-little-black-diamonds-with-a-question-mark/15138120)
2. [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf-8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)

For overcome this you can use `str_replace`.
replace all spaces with nothing in string. This will remove all spaces. **Not** recommended in sentences as it remove all spaces. **Good** for words.

```
$text = "  ひらがな  ";
$new_str = str_replace(' ', '', $text);
echo $new_str;    // returns ひらがな
```

If you want to remove spaces in beginning and ending use regex with `preg_replace`

```
print preg_replace( '/^s+|s+$/', '', "    ひらがな ひらがな" ); //return ひらがな ひらがな
```

trim is actually *nine times* faster. But you can use it.
Check speed comparison here.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4787238/10915534

Comment: It is deleting all the spaces.. However I only want to delete leading and trailing spaces